# Understanding this Event Example

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

After reading online tutorials regarding events , I think I almost have an idea of whats going on. I developed the following extremely simple code to trigger an event in case a value is greater than 5.I know the code is pretty useless but I am using it to get my point across. (Instead of a main I just used a button event to trigger the code.)

```
//declare the delegate
public delegate void MyDelegate(string str);

public class SomeClass
{
    public event MyDelegate MyEventFromDelegate;
    private int i;
    public int I
    {
            get
            { return i; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 5)
                {
                    MyEventFromDelegate("Value Greater than 5");
                    i = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = value;
                }
            }
    }

}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    { InitializeComponent();  }

    public void Method_To_Call(String rx)
    {   MessageBox.Show("This method will be called if greater than 5");}

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SomeClass a = new SomeClass();
        a.MyEventFromDelegate +=new MyDelegate(Method_To_Call);
        a.I = 12;
    }
}
```

The only concern I have here is when we want to raise an event with the statement

```
MyEventFromDelegate("Value Greater than 5");
```

What point is passing a parameters to the event is at this point if later (at button click event) we are actually going to assign it a function to call every time an event is triggered.

Comment: As per signature of `delegate` you're passing text message (string) to the event handler.

Comment: Well, use MessageBox.Show(rx) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your very simple example - there is no point, because SomeClass instance "a" is very short-lived, and because you are not using rx parameter passed to Method_To_Call.

Your form method button1_Click is connected to the button's Click event through a delegate. Button does not know what code will execute when it is clicked. All it has to do is to signal that is has been clicked. That signal is implemented using a delegate.

Your could have defined your delegate as having an integer parameter where the checked value is passed. Then although the event method would be invoked only when value is greater than 5, inside the event method you could do things differently depending on the actual value.

```
//declare the delegate
public delegate void MyDelegate(int aValue);

public class SomeClass
{
    public event MyDelegate MyEventFromDelegate;
    private int i;
    public int I
    {
            get
            { return i; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 5)
                {
                    MyEventFromDelegate(value);
                    i = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = value;
                }
            }
    }

}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();  
    }

    public void Method_To_Call(int aValue)
    {   
      MessageBox.Show("This method signals that value is greater than 5. Value=" + aValue.ToString());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SomeClass a = new SomeClass();
        a.MyEventFromDelegate +=new MyDelegate(Method_To_Call);
        a.I = 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, when dealing with custom events it's a good idea to accept an `EventArgs` parameter as well as an `object` reference to the sending object. This is pretty much standard practice. MSDN has some good information regarding custom events at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx